# How to fix scale_color_manual? This is not working properly anymore

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I am currently struggling with scale_color_manual in ggplot2, although this has never been a problem. I keep getting the error message: "Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 9 needed but only 0 provided." However, I have clearly provided enough colors, so it just doesn't seem to be registering.
Does anyone know what is going on/how I can fix this?

My ggplot2 package version is: 3.3.3.
Phyloseq Version is 1.30.0

```
library(phyloseq)
library(ggplot2)

data("GlobalPatterns")
GP <- prune_species(speciesSums(GlobalPatterns) > 0, GlobalPatterns)

#this usually works to assign colors below
cohortcol<- c("#70AD47","orange", "blue", "green","red",
  "yellow","purple","black","grey")

a<-plot_richness(GP, x="SampleType", color="SampleType",
  measures=c("Chao1", "Shannon")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=alpha(cohortcol, 0.7)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    legend.position="none", axis.title.y = element_blank())
print(a)
```

It then doesn't print a and gives me my error message. I get the same message if I were to remove cohortcol and just add colors as a vector instead instead.

GP is a phyloseq object.

Restarting R used to do the trick, however, even this has stopped working now.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Except for returning warnings for deprecated functions in phyloseq 1.32.0, this runs without errors and with the expected colours.

Comment: Yes, so this is my problem! It worked without a hitch for years and now doesn't - do you have any ideas what I could try to fix it?

Comment: I guess updating phyloseq might work, but given the deprecated functions you might have to update your scripts too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide names to the `cohortcol` so that `ggplot2` would know which color matching with what values in the data

Your code should work fine if you do this

```r
cohortcol<- c("#70AD47","orange", "blue", "green","red",
  "yellow","purple","black","grey")
names(cohortcol) <- c("Feces", "Freshwater", "Freshwater (creek)",
   "Mock", "Ocean", "Sediment (estuary)", "Skin", "Soil", "Tongue")
```

Here is the full working code. I didn't use phyloseq much but there are multiple warning about deprecated function in your code, pay attention to that too.

```r
library(phyloseq)
library(ggplot2)

data("GlobalPatterns")
GP <- prune_species(speciesSums(GlobalPatterns) > 0, GlobalPatterns)
#> Warning: 'prune_species' is deprecated.
#> Use 'prune_taxa' instead.
#> See help("Deprecated") and help("phyloseq-deprecated").
#> Warning: 'speciesSums' is deprecated.
#> Use 'taxa_sums' instead.
#> See help("Deprecated") and help("phyloseq-deprecated").

#this usually works to assign colors below
cohortcol<- c("#70AD47","orange", "blue", "green","red",
  "yellow","purple","black","grey")
names(cohortcol) <- c("Feces", "Freshwater", "Freshwater (creek)",
  "Mock", "Ocean", "Sediment (estuary)", "Skin", "Soil", "Tongue")

plot_richness(GP, x="SampleType", color="SampleType",
  measures=c("Chao1", "Shannon")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=alpha(cohortcol, 0.7)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    legend.position="none", axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>